# How to find a substring in a string and get its count using java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have been given a problem where I need to find the substring in a char array and have to count how many times that substring occurred.
For eg: "aabbcccddaabbbccc"
O/P:
aa:2
bb:1
ccc:2
dd:1
bbb:1

I tried this code but it is not giving me proper solution, if someone could suggest me what I am doing wrong

```
public class CountSubString {
     static Set set=new HashSet<>();
     static List list=new ArrayList<>();


    private static Map<char[], Integer> count(char[] charArrayToParse){
        Map<char[], Integer> subString = new HashMap<char[], Integer>();

        for (int i=0; i<charArrayToParse.length ;)
        {StringBuilder word= new StringBuilder();
            for (int j=i; j<charArrayToParse.length; j++) {

                if(charArrayToParse[i] == charArrayToParse[j]) {
                    word.append(charArrayToParse[j]);
                }
                else {
                    char[] subStringDone = word.toString().toCharArray();
                    if(subString.isEmpty())
                    subString.put(subStringDone, 1);

                    else if(subString.containsKey(subStringDone)) {
                        subString.put(subStringDone, subString.get(subStringDone)+1);
                    }
                    else {
                        subString.put(subStringDone, 1);
                    }

                //System.out.println("Word value are"+subString.get(key));
                    i=j;
                break;
                }

            }

        }
        Set<char[]> keyValues=  subString.keySet();
        for(char[] ch : keyValues) {
            if(subString.get(ch)>1) {
                 System.out.println(ch+"--->"+subString.get(ch));
            }
        }
        return subString;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "aaabbbccddddaaaeebbb"; 
        char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
        Map<char[], Integer> parsedArray= new HashMap<char[], Integer>();
    parsedArray= count(charArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: right now you have infinite loop, because you are not incrementing your ``i`` in for...

Comment: is bb=1 or bb=3?

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like a homework assignment, I'm not going to post a code solution, but I'll point you in the right direction.

Your double for loop is creating an infinite loop.  You're setting `i = j` and it's not getting set high enough to break out of the loop (never goes past 17).  Nested for loops in my book are usually a code smell, you've got something that should be broken into a few more functions (low cohesion).

In this case, your first function should be to break your string down into patterns.  Your nested for loops can be reduced down to a single loop, and each time a pattern is found, add it to a `Set<String>` instead of a map. This will prevent duplicates since a Set can only contain unique values.

You can then move on to the next part which is to figure out your pattern counts. Remember, in that case iterate over the string and check for matches.  You'll need to take into account that `aa` will also match `aaa` when doing your counts.

Comment: Thank you for your direction, but I am not getting how to reduce it to one loop as the problem I am facing is I need to match characters before breaking it into possible substrings.. Can you please suggest me a generic way for achieving this.. It is not a assignment it was asked in a interview so am trying to crack this..

Comment: I'd decompose your current method into two separate methods: `Set<String> parseKeys(String input)` and `Map<String, int> countMatches(String input, Set<String> keys)`

The first method iterates the string, and you compare the current letter to the previous letter.  If they're different, or the end of the array is reached, you add that sequence to the set. Since sets enforce uniqueness, you'll have substrings.  Your second method then takes those unique substrings (keys) and counts the times it appears in the input string.

Comment: I am not getting the way of how to compare the current letter and the previous letter without using two loops.. One more scenario is I have to match both the current indexes too as I have to add both the characters to substring if they are same.. For eg: aaabbbccc now here I have to add all the three a's so I have to add the current index as well as the next index too.

Comment: Try a local variable declared outside the for loop.  Something along the lines of `char previousLetter`, update it inside of the for loop. Try some code, and share it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use libraries? If so there's `StringUtils` in the `apache.commons.lang3` that can solve the problem in a single line like this:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("aabbcccddaabbbccc", "aa");
```

Comment: But I have to find all the substring and it's count, not only aa

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider.. for `bbaaarr` are there two sequences of `aa` or just one? My solution considers that there are two but it can be easily adjusted for the other case.

Comments in my code to help explain it:

---

```
/**
 * Returns the number of times the sequence occurs in the string.
 * @param seq - the sequence you are looking for
 * @param str - the string you are searching in
 */
private static int count(String seq, String str) {
    if(seq == null || seq.isEmpty() ||
       str == null || str.isEmpty() ){
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;

    // the first character of the sequence you are looking for
    final char seqChar = seq.charAt(0);

    // if there aren't seq.length() chars remaining then
    // it's no longer possible to match your sequence
    // so this is the max index to go to when looking for it
    final int maxIndex = str.length() - seq.length();

    // iterate through the characters in your string
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
        // when you find a character matching the start of your sequence
        // then compare the substring of equal length to your sequence
        // and if it matches then you have a match
        if (seqChar == str.charAt(i) &&
            seq.equals(str.substring(i, i + seq.length()))) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "aabbcccddaabbbccc";
    System.out.println(count("aa", s)); // 2
    // [aa]bbcccddaabbbccc
    // aabbcccdd[aa]bbbccc

    System.out.println(count("bb", s)); // 3
    // aa[bb]cccddaabbbccc
    // aabbcccddaa[bb]bccc
    // aabbcccddaab[bbccc

    System.out.println(count("cc", s)); // 4
    // aabb[cc]cddaabbbccc
    // aabbc[cc]ddaabbbccc
    // aabbcccddaabbb[cc]c
    // aabbcccddaabbbc[cc] 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code.. But here you have already taken the substring, but I am facing issues in finding substrings only from the array and also the string could be generic. So could you please suggest me a generic code to first find out its substring then its count